# Converting data sent from the client with RESTeasy

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, post, resteasy

I am developing some REST services, in J2EE environment, using RESTeasy library. 
If I have this @POST REST method:

```
@POST
@Path("/filter")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public List<Order> findOrders(
        @FormParam("orderfiltercriteria") OrderFilterCriteria orderFilterCriteria, 
        @FormParam("readcontext") OrderReadContext readContext, 
        @FormParam("querycontrol") QueryControl queryControl, 
        @FormParam("fetchpattern") FetchPattern fetchPattern, 
        @FormParam("loadpattern") LoadPattern loadPattern)
{
    ...
}
```

Supposing that the client sends these data through a form, and supposing that these are JSON string, how can I convert (server-side) these JSON strings in the correct way? For example, the JSON string for "readcontext" field, how can be converted properly into the OrderReadContext object?

I am using WidlFly 8.2 for the deploy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [@FormParam](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) documentation:

> The type T of the annotated parameter must either:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single >String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.